# Trouble with polygon to polygon "Join attributes by location"

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have two polygon vector layers - one of census tracts and one of water bodies. I would like to join a particular attribute from the water bodies table to each census tract, with the output being the sum of this attribute for all water bodies that border or intersect that census tract. I'm using the "Join attributes by location" tool, with summary of intersecting features checked. First, it tells me that there is a CRS error, which there is not - both layers are in the same CRS (EPSG:3310 - NAD83 / California Albers). Then, although it does not give me any errors, the output file only has null values for all the water body layer's features. The polygons in the output file are correct, however. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Using version 1.8. Thanks!